# Pandoc LaTeX to HTML and theorem environments

Tags: amsthm, pandoc

I am using Pandoc to convert LaTeX files to HTML files. Since these LaTeX files are mathematical documents, they contain theorem-like environments using `amsthm`. In the output HTML files these environments are missing.

More precisely, the contents of the environments are there but e.g. the word "Theorem" and the theorem number are missing.

Is there a way to automatically convert these environments as well?

**Edit:** Please find below a MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
  \begin{theorem}
    There is no largest prime number.
  \end{theorem}
\end{document}
```

which is compiled by `pdflatex` to (which is the desired output)
[image]

Using `pandoc` with the command

```
pandoc MWE_pandoc.tex -f latex -s --mathjax -o MWE_pandoc.html
```

this generates the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
   <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
   <title></title>
   <style type="text/css">code{white-space: pre;}</style>
 </head>
 <body>
   <p>There is no largest prime number.</p>
 </body>
```

which is (correctly) rendered to:

[image]

The pandoc version I used is pandoc 1.16.0.2

Comment: Could you provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/34551) ? A document sample in `tex` format, and maybe also what command you use, what version of pandoc, a screenshot of the output, or the expected output ?

Comment: Is using `htlatex` instead of `pandoc` an option? Something like `htlatex MWE_pandoc.tex "xhtml, mathml, charset=utf-8" " -cunihtf -utf8"` might do the job (at least, something like "Theorem 1" is written)

Comment: Actually, there has been some worked toward supporting `amsmath` in `pandoc`, cf. https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1608 and https://github.com/ickc/pandoc-amsthm and https://ickc.github.io/pandoc-amsthm/, but it looks like it is only from `markdown` to `latex` and `html`, not from `latex` to `html`…

Comment: @Clément: Thank you! `htlatex` might indeed be an option.

Comment: @Christian this feature has been added in `pandoc 2.10.1 (2020-07-23)`, see the [release notes](https://pandoc.org/releases.html) and [my post below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/638941).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `MWE_pandoc.tex` document, when processed with [tex4ht](https://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn.html), using

```
 make4ht -u MWE_pandoc.tex "html5,mathml"
```

(see [this page](https://tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn-commands.html) for other options) gives:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1 plus MathML 2.0//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/Math/DTD/mathml2/xhtml-math11-f.dtd" > 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
> 
<head><title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<meta name="originator" content="TeX4ht (http://www.tug.org/tex4ht/)" /> 
<!-- xhtml,html5,mathml,charset=utf-8,html --> 
<meta name="src" content="MWE_pandoc.tex" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="MWE_pandoc.css" /> 
</head><body 
>
  <div class="newtheorem">
<!--l. 7--><p class="noindent" ><span class="head">
<a 
 id="x1-2r1"></a>
<span 
class="cmbx-10x-x-109">Theorem 1.</span>  </span><span 
class="cmti-10x-x-109">There is no largest prime number.</span>
</p>
  </div>

</body></html>
```

which is rendered as

[image]

As a side note, I find `pandoc` more flexible to use, so if I were you, I would watch [this topic on github](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1608), to see if a reliable interface `amsmath` / `pandoc` sees the day. But that's probably just a matter of personal taste…

Comment: `tex4ht` supports `html5` in fact, but not by default. You can try `html5` option.

Comment: and command used to compile the example can be simplified to `make4ht -u MWE_pandoc.tex "html5,mathml"`

Comment: when used with `htlatex`, `html5` can be requested like this: `htlatex filename.tex "xhtml,html5"`. The docs haven't been updated yet, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my answer. I wasn't aware of those last developments of `htlatex`.

Comment: the code of `tex4ht` is updated regularly, but the fixes goes directly to TeX Live, not to CTAN, so the updates aren't visible at the first sight. This is quite unfortunate, but  there are some issues which prevents us from CTAN update.

Comment: @Clément Thank you for your answer. I will look into tex4ht. In case someone knows a pandoc solution I will wait a little bit before I accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue no longer exists with newer versions of `pandoc` (OP raising the question in 2017 and using `pandoc 1.16.0.2`).

Running

```bash
pandoc MWE_pandoc.tex -f latex -s --mathjax -o MWE_pandoc.html
```

generates the HTML `<body>`

```html
<body>
<div class="theorem">
<p><strong>Theorem 1</strong>.  <em>There is no largest prime number.</em></p>
</div>
</body>
```

rendering

[image]

To sum up, when properly called, `pandoc` will generate:

- enclosing `<div class="theorem">` tag that can be used for further styling
- typesetting in of the theorem's name (**bold**) and body (*italic*)

---

MWE Tested with `pandoc --version`:

```
pandoc 2.17.1.1
Compiled with pandoc-types 1.22.1, texmath 0.12.4, skylighting 0.12.2,
citeproc 0.6.0.1, ipynb 0.2
```

---

**Edit:**

I also tested the available [`pandoc/core`](https://hub.docker.com/r/pandoc/core) Docker images and the above should work for `pandoc --version >=  2.10.1`, i.e. `pandoc/core:2.10.1` and subsequent versions.

According to the [release notes](https://pandoc.org/releases.html), the feature was added in `pandoc 2.10.1 (2020-07-23)`. Search for `LaTeX reader` in order to spot further improvements over time.

[image]